# How to handle exception in controller by showing error in jsp file?

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

I have a controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/take-item/{itemId}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String takeItem(final ModelMap model, @PathVariable final Long itemId) {
    try {
        scanService.takeItem(currentUser.getUserId(), itemId);
    } catch (NoItemsInStockException e) {
        // Not sure what to do here.
    }
    return "redirect:/";
}
```

and a jsp file which this controller redirects to :

```
<c:forEach var="item" items="${items}">
    <form action="/take-item/${item.id}" method="POST">
        <div class="item rounded m10">
            <img src="${item.image}" width="150" height="150"/>
            <h5>${item.productTitle}</h5>
            <p>${item.price} <span class="nortal">LT</span></p>
            <button class="btn btn-success">Imu!</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</c:forEach>
```

How can I show an error in this jsp file when there are no items left ? If you need anythin else please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
<c:forEach var="item" items="${items}">
           <form action="/take-item/${item.id}" method="POST">
                <c:if test="item.quantity=='0'">
                    <h4 style="color:red"> Item out of stock</h4>
                </c:if>
                <div class="item rounded m10">
                   <img src="${item.image}" width="150" height="150"/>
                    <h5>${item.productTitle}</h5>
                    <p>${item.price} <span class="nortal">LT</span></p>
                    <button class="btn btn-success">Imu!</button>
                </div>
             </form>
       </c:forEach>
```

Comment: I want to display these items anyway, just an error message above them that item you wanted is no longer in stock.

Comment: What will be the condition for an empty item? is there any stock field?

Comment: Yeah there's Item.quantity